# why my state didn't update when i use history.push()?

Tags: reactjs, browser-history

i use history.push like this :

```
state = {
        resumeList : [],
      }
     Searchinp = (event) => {
           event.preventDefault()
           const props = this.props
               console.log(props)
           const searchValue = event.target.value
           this.setState({
               Search:searchValue
           })
           console.log(searchValue)
           props.history.push({search: `phrase=${searchValue}` }); 
          reqhandler({
            url: exporturl.getportofoliorequest(),
            method : "get",
            headers : {
                "Authorization": `Bearer ${gettoken().acctoken}`       
             },
             params : {
                 lang : getLang(),
                 phrase : event.target.search.value
             }
            }).then(res => {
                console.log(res.data)
                this.setState({
                    ...this.state,
                    resumeList : res.data.results,
                })
                console.log(this.state.resumeList)  
                }).catch(err => {
                    console.log("Error :" , err)
                })
           }
```

when i use to the history.poush() my state didn't update but url is changed . 
 but when i remove it , my state updated 
please help me

Answer (score 1):

> history.push sends you to another page (redirect)  so it stops the
>   execution of your function

Always use history.push at the end of your function (or where you want to finish your function)

```
state = {
        resumeList : [],
      }
     Searchinp = (event) => {
           event.preventDefault()
           const props = this.props
               console.log(props)
           const searchValue = event.target.value
           this.setState({
               Search:searchValue
           })
           console.log(searchValue)

          reqhandler({
            url: exporturl.getportofoliorequest(),
            method : "get",
            headers : {
                "Authorization": `Bearer ${gettoken().acctoken}`       
             },
             params : {
                 lang : getLang(),
                 phrase : event.target.search.value
             }
            }).then(res => {
                console.log(res.data)
                this.setState({
                    ...this.state,
                    resumeList : res.data.results,
                })
               props.history.push({search: `phrase=${searchValue}` }); 
                console.log(this.state.resumeList)  
                }).catch(err => {
                    console.log("Error :" , err)
                })
           }
```

Comment: state updated , my issue is :  my state that maped in a table didn't show anything ,   Can you guide me?

Answer (score 0):

Navigate to other component as a callback after updating state.

```
reqhandler({
            url: exporturl.getportofoliorequest(),
            method : "get",
            headers : {
                "Authorization": `Bearer ${gettoken().acctoken}`       
             },
             params : {
                 lang : getLang(),
                 phrase : event.target.search.value
             }
            }).then(res => {
                console.log(res.data)
                this.setState({
                    ...this.state,
                    resumeList : res.data.results,
                },{
               props.history.push({search: `phrase=${searchValue}` });  
                })
                }).catch(err => {
                    console.log("Error :" , err)
                })
```

Comment: state updated , my issue is : my state that maped in a table didn't show anything , Can you guide me?